# Is there a one word synonym for hometown hero?

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for a word similar to hometown hero, or someone who willingly helps those within their community who are in need/danger. This is different to helping as a part of a job (eg. doctor, social worker), but rather helping because they choose to. Something similar to an idol, Samaritan or savior but without any religious associations, if that makes sense.

Comment: Community stalwart.

Comment: “hometown hero” is an alliteration and is perfectly clear and concise.  Why do you think you need a single word when two is perfect?

Comment: According to some classifiers, 'hometown hero' is a compound noun is a 'word'. I'd agree with Jim, and almost always choose it over mahmud's  'Johnny-on-the-spot'.

Comment: I suppose I was looking for a more generic term. It could be just me, but "hometown hero" has a strong country/rural vibe. Would you for example call someone from New York a hometown hero?

Comment: Much of NY state is country/rural. If you mean the city of NY, then yes 'hometown hero' can work If NYC is the person's hometown.

Comment: (a) you are not going to get one word and (b) hometown hero is perfect, even for NYC or Chicago or Los Angeles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seek something comparable to hometown hero.  Hero suggests someone from the town who returned from war or sports or whatever as a hero, or perhaps once helped in a flood or other disaster.  "**Community stalwart**"might serve your purpose better.--A loyal, reliable, and hard-working supporter of or participant in an organization or team," (ODO), the team being the community.  Johnny-on-the-spot does not cover the idea of continuous service, but may relate only to a one-time event.

Answer (score 0):

> **[Johnny–on–the–spot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Johnny%E2%80%93on%E2%80%93the%E2%80%93spot)**: (M-W)
>
> *A person who is on hand and ready to perform a service or respond to
>   an emergency*.
>
> **Johnny-on-the-spot** ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/johnny-on-the-spot))
>
> *a person who is on hand to perform a service, seize an opportunity, deal with an emergency, etc.*
>
> E.g. I'll be *Johnny-on-the-spot* all right, and have it ready for
>   you.

Comment: Misses the *hometown* aspect.

Comment: There may be such a Johnny in every hometown or community!

Comment: Johnny on the Spot also means [this](http://www.johnnyonthespot.com/).

Answer (score -5):

Why did nearly everyone here decide to comment with TOTAL non-answers?

Anyway, here are some attempts:

- Peacemaker
- Vigilante
- Helper
- Defender
- Keeper
- Philanthrope
- Hawkshaw
- Sheriff
- Steward
- Guardian
- Guard
- Shield
- Sentinel
- Sentry
- Knight
- Gallant
- Champion
- Gendarme
- Ward
- Warden
- Watchdog
- Lookout
- Hero (I know, a reductive answer, but worth considering)

Hopefully these at least help jar some thoughts or imagery.

Comment: Please see the tour, which will detail how to answer: https://english.stackexchange.com/tour. 

Also consider referring to the code of conduct; your answer may be deleted based on the superfluous commentary: https://english.stackexchange.com/conduct